# Error loading SSO Token: The SSO access token has either expired or is otherwise invalid

Tags: centos7, aws-cli, php-8.2

I am using Centos 7 inside docker, with the environment php 8.2, apache, aws cli (aws-cli/2.0.30 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.15.49-linuxkit-pr botocore/2.0.0dev34).
inside my docker container, there is one file php file there I have write the code to check is aws cli is accessible or not.

When I attempt to access the browser, it displays an error message: 'Error loading SSO Token: The SSO access token has either expired or is otherwise invalid.' However, when I run the same file inside the container, it functions as expected. It should behave the same way in the browser as well."

FYI: This is my code.

```
<?php
if (is_file('/.aws/credentials')) {
  echo "AWS Credentials found";
}

$env = 'AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2; AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT=text AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/.aws/config AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=/.aws/credentials';

echo "<br>";

echo "CLI S3 Access: ";

exec("$env /usr/bin/aws s3 ls s3://picto-us-east-2-imagery-01/_healthcheck/README.txt 2>&1", $output, $return);

if ($return === 0) {
  echo "success";
} else {
  echo "failed";
  echo "<br>The command failed, check your saml2aws config.<br> Output: <pre>" . print_r($output, true) . "</pre>";
}

echo "<br>";

$output = array();

echo "CLI Secrets Manager: ";

exec("$env /usr/bin/aws secretsmanager get-random-password 2>&1 ", $output, $return);

if ($return === 0) {
  echo "success";
} else {
  echo "failed";
  echo "<br>The command failed, check your saml2aws config.<br> Output: <pre>" . print_r($output, true) . "</pre>";
}

echo "<br>";
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of effort, I finally found the solution. It was a permission issue. I just **granted 777 permission** to the `root` folder.
Now, how do I debug this code? I used the `--debug` flag at the end of the AWS command like this:

`exec("$env /usr/bin/aws secretsmanager get-random-password --debug 2>&1 ", $output, $return);`

I want to express my gratitude to [Avinash Dalvi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6285054/avinash-dalvi) for helping me fix this code. They actually gave me the idea to use the --debug flag and read the error.

**Debug issue:**

[image: Debug issue]

**After fix :**
[image: after fix]